# MYSQL: Get second last record for every customer from a table

Tags: mysql, sql

my table looks like this

```
ID  DATE      customer_id
 1   2020-10-01   10
 2   2020-10-01   11
 3   2020-10-02   10
 4   2020-10-03   10
 5   2020-10-03   11
```

What i am trying to fetch from the list based on second last ID for each customer

```
ID  DATE      customer_id
 2   2020-10-01   11
 3   2020-10-02   10
```

Comment: And what did you try so far and what is the problem? Please, provide any evidence of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `ROW_NUMBER` is suitable here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY customer_id ORDER BY DATE DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT ID, DATE, customer_id
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 2;
```

Comment: To my mind, 'second last *id*' implies ordering by id